# Transposing Rows to Columns and having values flow down in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, transpose

I am using TSQL.

If I have the following results:

[image]

And I want to transpose this to be like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

I have the following query:

```
WITH q AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM tableOne
    WHERE ID = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT m.*
    FROM tableOne m
    JOIN ON m.ParentID = q.ID
)
SELECT *
FROM q
```

This gives me all of the items underneath the specified node including the specified node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be easy for us to help you if you add scripting data and not an image. Note that `tbl` is the name of your table, it is called 3 times. Try this:

```
select 
    a.fieldValue company, 
    b.fieldValue department, 
    c.fieldValue Job
from tbl a 
inner join tbl b on a.parentId is null and a.id=b.parentID
inner join tbl c on b.id= c.parentID
```

If it does not bring desired results please add data as text and let me know, I could modify the query

Comment: Just for fun I validated you solution and it works just fine.  +1 The joins didn't occur to me

Comment: Yes, this does appear to be what I needed! Thanks Horaciux!

Answer (score 0):

Another option (assuming this is NOT a jagged hierarchy).

This is a standard Recursive CTE, with a little twist in the final SELECT

**Example**

```
;with cteP as (
      Select ID
            ,ParentID 
            ,PathID = cast(FieldValue as varchar(max))
      From   YourTable
      Where  ParentID is Null
      Union  All
      Select ID  = r.ID
            ,ParentID  = r.ParentID 
            ,PathID = cast(p.PathID+'|||'+r.FieldValue as varchar(max))
      From   YourTable r
      Join   cteP p on r.ParentID  = p.ID)
Select ID
      ,B.*
 From  cteP A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Company    = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Department = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Job        = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace(PathID,'|||','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as X 
             ) B
  Where ID not in (Select Distinct ParentID from YourTable where ParentID is not null)
  Order By PathID
```

**Returns**

[image]